# C# Getting StreamWriter to Write to text file

Tags: c#, windows, forms

I have reviewed my Professor's lecture numerous times, reviewed the text book, searched endlessly online for answers, and tried every reasonable suggested fix out there.  I am certainly missing something.  The address book writes to the list box, the file is created, but the name and address is not written to the file.  Any help with what I am missing would be greatly appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;


namespace LAB7A
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        List<Person> people = new List<Person>();
        class Person
        {
            public string Name
            {
                get;
                set;
            }

            public string Email
            {
                get;
                set;
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            try
            {
               StreamWriter address = new StreamWriter("addressbook.txt");
               address.WriteLine(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text);
            }
            catch (DirectoryNotFoundException exc)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Directory Could Not Be Found");
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)

        {

            Person p = new Person();
            p.Name = textBox1.Text;
            p.Email = textBox2.Text;
            people.Add(p);
            listBox1.Items.Add(p.Name);
            listBox1.Items.Add(p.Email);



            //StreamWriter address.WriteLine(textBox1.Text);
            //address.WriteLine(textBox2.Text);
            //listBox1.Items.Add(textBox1.Text);
            //listBox1.Items.Add(textBox2.Text);
        }

        private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are saving data to file on form load when all fields are empty. Move writing code to some button click handler after you have chance to type values in the text fields.

You are also using version of [TextWriter.WriteLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/60scc1f1.aspx) method that take format as first argument. Unless you really want to do that either 2 separate `WriteLine` calls or one with correct format string would probably do what you want.

Also make sure to close/dispose your stream writer so it commits changes to file and closes the file. Usual way to do that is to use `using`:

```
using (var writer = new StreamWriter("addressbook.txt"))
{
     writer.WriteLine("First textbox:{0}, second:{1}", textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text);
}
```

Comment: Very important that last bit - the `StreamWriter` will most likely not flush its contents until `Flush` is called explicitly or the object is disposed. Wrapping it in a using statement ensures that the contents are written and the stream is closed (closing the stream also stops the file from being locked by the process after the write has completed)

Answer (score 1):

Try either calling Flush or Close on the stream.  Best practice is to wrap it in a using though.

```
using(StreamWriter address = new StreamWriter("addressbook.txt"))
{
    ...
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.aspx

Scroll down to the example code.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add complete address,try this:

```
 private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {

           using (StreamWriter address = new StreamWriter("d:\\addressbook.txt"))//Add correct address
            {
              address.WriteLine(textBox1.Text + textBox2.Text);
              //OR
              address.WriteLine(string.Format("Name:{0}, Email:{1}", textBox1.Text,    textBox2.Text));
            }
        }
        catch (DirectoryNotFoundException exc)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Directory Could Not Be Found");
        } 
    }
```

Comment: This is really helpful. However, I need it to write what the user puts in the text box and what I am trying is failing.  Forgive me if this is elementary, but I am just learning c#.  This is what I am using and while it doesn't throw any error, it doesn't write the name and email address the user puts in the text boxes.

Comment: address.WriteLine(textBox1.Text + textBox2.Text);

Comment: instead of  `address.WriteLine("asd");` use `address.WriteLine(textBox1.Text + textBox2.Text);` or  `address.WriteLine(string.Format("Name:{0}, Email:{1}", textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text));`

Comment: How is this different than what I posted above?  I believe that is exactly what I have and it still doesn't write that information to the file

Comment: I just tried the string.Format("Name:{0}, Email:{1}", textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text and the only output I get is the text written Name and Email, obviously because it is a string.  The problem is that it doesn't write the information put in the text box upon clicking the Add Contact button

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28598/discussion-between-irsog-and-webby68)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.  You were very helpful in pointing me in the right direction, but I got it fixed with another answer from above.